# should this code work for including in a helper file to rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following sample code that is using a vanilla spec_helper. I'm trying to use the sign_in_as but am getting an error saying it doesn't exist. I hadn't really seen this config syntax before so I'm not sure if this is being used right. Any help would be appreciated? thx

in helpers/sign_in_helpers.rb

```
module SignInHelpers
  def say_hello
    puts 'hello'
  end

  def sign_in
    sign_in_as 'person@example.com'
  end

  def sign_in_as email
    visit root_path
    fill_in 'Email address', with: email
    click_button 'Sign In'
  end
end     

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SignInHelpers
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors in your code.

1. you should have this code on top of the file

   require 'spec_helper'
2. The place to put the file is `spec/support`, not `spec/helpers`

Also, for the following code, better to keep them all inside spec/spec_helper.rb inside the configure block, though your way should work as well.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SignInHelpers
end
```

By the way, better to define the type as your helper are for features only, and not going to work in controller tests.

```
config.include SignInHelpers type: :feature
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes.  Your call looks like a valid use of the include syntax

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module